# Cannot install vmware-tools

Tags: 11.04, installation, virtualization, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install vmware-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42687/cannot-install-vmware-tools)

I encounter this error:

The path "/usr/src/linux/include" is not an existing directory.